# PHP: MYSQLi query returns no results when search parameter includes single quote

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP script that searches a MySQL table. It works fine for regular text searches, but it returns no results when the search string includes a single quotation mark (such as the word `O'Brien`). Running the equivalent SQL in phpMyAdmin does return results.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');    

if (isset($_GET["q"]))
{
    $search = $_GET["q"];
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField LIKE ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$param = '%' . $search . '%';
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

How do I handle strings like `O'Brien` so that this returns results?

Comment: Have you verified the value of `$search`? If you are on a very old server magic quotes could theoretically be enabled...

Comment: Also for the exact values in your database, are they exactly what you expect them to be?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it looks like the problem was some old code that used filter_var:

```
filter_var($search, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
```

When I remove this, the query works as expected.

Thanks for your time!

Paul

Comment: To clarify, this would mean that the sanitize filter was altering the input data, and the query was failing to match the altered string in the database because no entry matched it. *Not* because of anything remotely related to SQL injection like everyone seems to have latched onto regardless of the fact that you are properly using a prepared statement. Had you included the above code in your original question the problem would have been at least visible to us.

Comment: Who the heck mentioned SQL injection?

Comment: @worldofjr equating stray quotes improperly included into SQL queries with SQL injection, that would mean both you, and the other guy who already deleted his answer.

Comment: @Sammitch My answer uses a method that escapes special characters. There would be no problem with SQL injection since the OP is using prepared statements (indeed it should also avoid problems with special characters, but it depends what's stored in the database).

Comment: @worldofjr I'm not going to argue this point, jeroen has already pointed out the flaws in your reasoning in the comments on your [incorrect] answer.

Comment: @Sammitch Fine, but don't accuse me of relating this to SQL injection when I did nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli::real_escape_string()`;

```
$sql = $mysqli->real_escape_string($sql); // where $mysqli is your connection
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not necessary when you use a prepared statement and it would actually add slashes to your variable where there are probably none in the database.

Comment: @jeroen It shouldn't be a problem with prepared statements, but it clearly is. Thinking about it, I suspect the OP has got magic quotes switched on, but if they can't change that (very possible) then this is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: No, it's the other way around, if magic quotes really is enabled, the input would already have quotes and they would need to be stripped to match a database where the quotes are not escaped with a backslash...